# Scanning a .txt file for a particular value in C

Tags: c

I've been playing around with reading from text files and have come up with a problem I'm uncertain how to solve.

Lets say I have the following text file:

```
0004    78  119
0014    76  118
0024    78  117
0034    74  118
0044    76  119
0054    75  116
0064    78  119
0074    79  120
0084    81  122
0094    82  124
```

Column 1 represents the time index, while column 2 and column 3 are values 1 and 2 at those time indexes. What I'm trying to do is have a user be able to input enter in a time index and then to have the program spit out, for example, value 1 and that time index.

For example, a user input of 0094 would spit back the value 82 respectively. I'm struggling to wrap my mind around an effective way of solving this problem. My initial thought would be to read the files into a matrix and then searching through the matrix for whatever value the user inputted but I'm uncertain how to proceed.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please start with posting some code that opens a text file, reads in 3 values from each line, and prints them. You know how to do that. Second step is to examine the first field and see if it matches the user's requirement. EDIT sorry you just deleted "know how to read from files"

Answer (score 1):

If the you want the user to be able to make multiple searches, I'd recommend storing all the information into memory, let's say into an array of structures containing a field for each column of your file.

Otherwise, you can just read your file line by line, and stop when the requested result is found.